# Clone base environment in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

My conda version is 4.7.11. I am trying to clone the base env to a new one so I can install some specific packages and will not mess up the base environment. 
I tried as some other answers suggested:

```
conda create --name <myenv> --clone base
```

and

```
conda create --name <myenv> --clone root
```

But none of them works. The message from terminal is "The system cannot find the file specified".

Below is my cuurent env list:

```
base                  *  D:\LabTest\Dave\Anaconda
dlc-windowsCPU           D:\LabTest\Dave\Anaconda\envs\dlc-windowsCPU
dlc-windowsGPU           D:\LabTest\Dave\Anaconda\envs\dlc-windowsGPU
dlc-windowsGPU-dave      D:\LabTest\Dave\Anaconda\envs\dlc-windowsGPU-dave
dlc-windowsGPU-yc        D:\LabTest\Dave\Anaconda\envs\dlc-windowsGPU-yc
```

I also cannot clone from my anaconda navigator.

Don't know what to do.

Comment: As of conda 4.11.0, this works: conda create --name <myenv> --clone base

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would recommend that you try the method as shown on this [official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments). In summary, you can get all the list of modules installed in the virtual environment, save it as a `.txt` file, and create a new environment from that `.txt` file. For example,

```sh
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
```

Then, create a new environment using that specification.

```sh
conda create --name myenv --file spec-file.txt
```

While this is not exactly "cloning" the base environment, you should be able to reproduce a virtual environment identical to the base through this process.

Comment: Attempting to clone the base environment concludes but with a message saying that a number of packages could not be cloned out of the root environment.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I did this and it works well!

Comment: @G.T. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 39):

You just have to refer to the base environment, which is called `base` and not `root`:

```
conda create --name <myenv> --clone base
```

Comment: OP specifically said in the original question that that's the first thing he tried. Should work normally, but didn't.

Answer (score 6):

What I usually do when creating new env is the below command:

```
conda create --clone pytorch --name pytorch1.6
```

Where pytorch is the environment that I am cloning to pytorch1.6 which I'll be updating to the latest nightly build. My reason for cloning is to avoid configuration of Cuda all over again :)
Documentation or rather official cheatsheet lives [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: best answer creating a true clone with fewest steps.  No need to create the .txt file...

Comment: does not answer OP