# Update python from 3.5 to 3.6 in conda

Tags: python, version, conda, upgrade

I want to upgrade my python version from 3.5 to 3.6 to use the new features.

I first copy the base env as base3.6 using [Clone base environment in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067635/7194271),

then I want to upgrade the python3.5 to 3.6 using `conda install python=3.6`, but I have this error

```
(base3.6) D:\Desktop\GOC-VRPTW-master>conda install python=3.6
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - defaults/win-64::psutil==4.3.1=py35_0 -> python=3.5 -> python_abi=[build=*_cp35m] -> pypy[version='<0a0']
  - python=3.6
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Similar problem, but different in details [conda install python=3.6 UnsatisfiableError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555097/7194271)

Comment: I tried ```conda install anaconda=4.3``` and ```conda install -c anaconda python=3.6``` they didn't work.

Comment: Consider making a new environment (ideally with Python 3.7 or newer)

Comment: It looks that there is no better choice T.T @MattThompson Thank you~

Comment: Creating a new environment is not a compromise - it is the better choice. Trying to mutate the Python version within an existing environment has no upsides over creating a fresh environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that reinstalling a new environment is a better choice.