# In VS Code, ~/conda/bin/python3.10.10 and ~/conda/envs/my_env/bin/conda3.10.10 differ, and the latter breaks imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, miniconda

The behavior is this:

- for the base conda env, vscode finds all imports
- for a freshly created `my_env` conda environment - with the same pip-installed modules - vscode reports that those modules cannot be found.

The base env was copied as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067635/9232100). Switching in vscode from base env to my_env broke the imports. Both were reported as using python 3.10.10.

After much looking and reading many stackoverflow entries, I found that the two python3.10 binaries mentioned above report as version 3.10.10, but are not the same (simple diff).

Moving `~/conda/envs/my_env/bin/conda3.10.10`  out of the way and linking `~/conda/bin/python3.10.10`  to  `~/conda/envs/my_env/bin/`, the problem is resolved. I made no other changes - just that one.

The strangest bit is that the verbose versions for the two are the same:

```
$ ~/conda/bin/python3.10 --version -VV
Python 3.10.10 (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:45:11) [GCC 11.2.0]

~/conda/envs/my_env/bin/python3.10.save --version -VV
Python 3.10.10 (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:45:11) [GCC 11.2.0]
```

What I can't figure out is why they differ and what causes the imports for my_env to fail.

While the fix works, it's not a viable solution.

Any idea why using the former works and the latter differs? And to whom I should report this?